# Python, how to move dict under itself with a new attribute? Eg dict['key'] = dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an array of very large dictionaries, and need to put each dict itself under a new key.

I know `dict['key'] = dict` won't work and will result a recursive dict in python. Currently, I'm doing something like:

```
new_dict['key'] = old_dict
```

and it will waste memory, is there a better way doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a small bit to mgilson's answer:

```
new_dict['key'] = old_dict
```

will not be a waste of memory. This assignment operator only assigns *a reference* to old_dict. Elements from old_dict aren't copied.

But regardless of how you do it - directly or via a different variable name, you'll get circular reference, which is valid for some usages and not valid for some other.

Comment: Totally forgot objects are passed by reference, ty

Answer (score 4):

A `dict` *can* hold a reference to itself:

```
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> d['self'] = d
>>> d
{'self': {...}, 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> d['self']['self']['self']['self']['foo']
'bar'
```

Of course, there are *some* things that you can't do (e.g. dump it to `json`):

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

If you actually need to persist this in some way, then you probably don't have another option other than to copy it when you add it to itself:

```
d = {'foo': 'bar'}
d['self'] = d.copy()
```

Or writing some sort of custom logic so that when deserializing, you replace certain sentinel values with the `dict` itself (which may or may not work depending on why you need this particular feature)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to dump the dict in database, a recursive dict won't work.